# Resize images in directory

Tags: python, perl, image, resize, image-scaling

I have a directory full of images that I would like to resize to around 60% of their original size.

How would I go about doing this? Can be in either Python or Perl

Cheers

Eef

Comment: I'm not sure. First of all - it doesn't say it's one time job. Second - "Irfan View" might not be an option - for example due to operating system constraints. Third - ImageMagick is so complex, that even using it as a batch tool is kind of programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using mogrify, part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)? If you really need to control this from Perl, then you could use [Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Magick), [Image::Resize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Resize) or [Imager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Imager).

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do it programatically, which I assume is the case, use PIL to resize e.g.

```
newIm = im.resize((newW, newH)
```

then save it to same file or a new location.

Go through the folder recursively and apply resize function to all images.

I have come up with a sample script which I think will work for you. You can improve on it: Maybe make it graphical, add more options e.g. same extension or may be all png, resize sampling linear/bilinear etc

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image

def resize(folder, fileName, factor):
    filePath = os.path.join(folder, fileName)
    im = Image.open(filePath)
    w, h  = im.size
    newIm = im.resize((int(w*factor), int(h*factor)))
    # i am saving a copy, you can overrider orginal, or save to other folder
    newIm.save(filePath+"copy.png")

def bulkResize(imageFolder, factor):
    imgExts = ["png", "bmp", "jpg"]
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(imageFolder):
        for fileName in files:
            ext = fileName[-3:].lower()
            if ext not in imgExts:
                continue

            resize(path, fileName, factor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    imageFolder=sys.argv[1] # first arg is path to image folder
    resizeFactor=float(sys.argv[2])/100.0# 2nd is resize in %
    bulkResize(imageFolder, resizeFactor)
```

Answer (score 10):

Can it be in shell?

```
mkdir resized
for a in *.jpg; do convert "$a" -resize 60% resized/"$a"; done
```

If you have > 1 core, you can do it like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -P3 -I XXX convert XXX -resize 60% resized/XXX
```

-P3 means that you want to resize up to 3 images at the same time (parallelization).

If you don't need to keep originals you can use mogrify, but I prefer to use convert, and then rm ...; mv ... - just to be on safe side if resizing would (for whatever reason) fail.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php), it's an interface to the popular [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite of command line tools to do just this kind of stuff. [PythonMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python) is available as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use Python with PIL (Python Image Library). Of course there are specialized programs to do this.

Many people use PIL to such things. Look at: [Quick image resizing with python](http://pandemoniumillusion.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/quick-image-resizing-with-python/)

PIL is very powerful and recently I have found this recipe:
[Putting watermark to images in batch](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576818/)

Answer (score 0):

do you need to just resize it or you want to resize programmatically?
If just resize use PixResizer. http://bluefive.pair.com/pixresizer.htm